# Tcp-Listener Doesnt Always Catch Connections

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

So the problem I'm having is sometimes I start it and it doesnt detect the client connecting but other times i start it, it works fine no issues. For whatever reason I get more success building it in release mode than I do when i run it in debug mode which baffles me, is my code good?

To clarify the AcceptCallback should be called whenever a connection is detected but sometimes when running it, it doesnt seem to be listening for connections at all, my port isnt blocked either

Server Code:

```
    Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public void Start()
    {
        drawLogo();
        Log.Write("Starting Server...");
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
        server.Listen(5);
        Log.Write("Started!");
        Log.Write("Listening on port " + 1234 + "\nWaiting for clients");

        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Log.Write("called");
        Socket socket;
        try
        {
            socket = server.EndAccept(ar);

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
        userList.Add(new Users(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), socket));
        Log.Success("Client Connected!");
        sendAdminsLog("GREEN " + "Client Connected!");
        socket.BeginReceive(g_buffer, 0, g_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }
```

Client Code:

```
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);//
    private void Connect()
    {
        //right now testing is being done on local host 
        //we'll use a while loop until a connection is made, might want to add a counter later
        while (!client.Connected)
        {
            //using a try and catch so if we get an error the program doesnt just crash
            //and we can close the program with reasoning behind it
            try
            {
                //we'll change the ip to an md5 encryption so login server doesnt get ddosed
                client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("73.73.34.126"), 1234);//IPAddress.Loopback, 1234);
                return;
            }
            //here we catch an error and can do whatever we want to it, we'll probs close the program for security
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server, check your connection\nPress retry to try again or cancel to exit", "Unable To Connect", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
```

**Solution**

It seems my windows firewall was the culprit here. I thought I turned it all off already but I guess not. Thanks for everyone who tried helping

Comment: Please ensure you read what tags are for before using them. The `[visual-studio]` tag is intended only for questions about Visual Studio (the application).

Comment: I would advise beginning to accept clients again immediately after you call `EndAccept`, although I don't think this is necessarily related to your problem.

Comment: Can you advise if "randomly doesn't work at all" means that the connection times out on the client (i.e. as if the server isn't there), or if the client doesn't end up in the users list? If the client doesn't end up in the users list, is the list something like a `ConcurrentBag` or other thread-safe collection?

Comment: Im sorry "randomly doesnt work at all" might mean what you said but anything that trys to connect to that port like port checkers would show a message or crash the server but it seems to be not listening on the port at times

Comment: Crash the server? That definitely sounds like you might have a threading issue. Try changing `userList` to a thread-safe collection.

Comment: thats not my current issue, my current issue is the server is not listening...

Answer (score 0):

It seems my windows firewall was the culprit here. After Turning it all off it started accepting connections like normal